# Generate insert scripts for data using Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I noticed the possibility to "Generate Create Script..." that gives me the "CREATE TABLE" script (and PRIMARY KEY, INDEXES...) that is useful, but I couldn't find an option to get insert scripts, so my question is:
is there a way to generate insert scripts for a specific query or an entire table using Visual Studio (or specifically the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio)?
Or maybe is there an extension that does this?

I'm using VS 2012.

Thanks in advice